# Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.22:install-node-and-npm: error code 503 from the server

Tags: node.js, maven, npm

On trying to build the project, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.22:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project ProjectName: Could not download Node.js from: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.40/x64/node.exe: Got error code 503 from the server.
```

This is my pom.xml implementation of `com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin`.
Everything seems to be fine, there are no compilation errors, but on trying to build, the above error is showing up.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- NB! Set <version> to the latest released version of frontend-maven-plugin, like in README.md -->
    <version>0.0.22</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v0.10.40</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>2.5.1</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>grunt build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>grunt</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>build --no-color</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using it behind a proxy.

This version of plugin was released in February 2015. And there is a [reported issue](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/565) which is related to this problem.

```xml
<groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
<artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<!-- NB! Set <version> to the latest released version of frontend-maven-plugin, like in README.md -->
<version>0.0.22</version>
```

The answer is in the question:

> Set  to the latest released version of frontend-maven-plugin

Comment: But the problem is I am using maven 3.3.9 and the latest version of this is not compatible with it. This is a legacy application so am not sure whether it is safe to update the version of maven